# Visual Studio is unable to locate the .NET.Core SDK when it runs an Xamarin App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, .net-core, sdk

Every time when I run a Xamarin App from Visual Studio, I get the Error message below:

> Unable to locate the `.NET Core SDK`. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in `global.json` (if any) matches the installed version.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem after installing some updates. this solution fixed it for me. https://superuser.com/a/1457932/999776

Answer (score 3):

Open your console and run

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

To make sure you have the proper SDKs installed. Then [follow the microsoft resolution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/896868/unable-to-locate-the-net-core-sdk-after-1650-previ.html)

> Ways to work around this:
>
> - Install .NET Core SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download.
> - Don't use global.json. I would be happy to hear why you chose to use it.
> - Include a roll forward indicator such as the following which will ensure running with any SDK higher than 3.1.100

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.100",
    "rollForward": "latestMajor"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the Package Manager Console? Because I get this Error: The term 'dotnet' is not recognized.

Comment: Which console do you mean that I should use?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras where do you include that roll forward information?

Answer (score 0):

adding in appsettings.json, add below tag with your version:

```js
"sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.402",
    "rollForward": "latestMajor"
},
```

restart VS, opened project without the subject issue.